# Backfill for new index in existing dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an existing dynamodb table. I wanted to create a index on this existing table, which has some data already. But when I am doing that, I still cannot see any existing data in this index in console? Any idea why?

So, doesn't it backfill the old data in the index? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backfilling should take place automatically, but it takes time. the more data you have in your table the longer it will take for the backfill process to complete. you can speed it up by provisioning additional capacity to the index (which, naturally, you'll need to pay for it)